# Why can't we overload "=" using friend function?

Tags: c++

Why it is not allowed to overload "=" using friend function?
I have written a small program but it is giving error.

```
class comp
{
int real;
int imaginary;
public:
comp(){real=0; imaginary=0;}
void show(){cout << "Real="<<real<<" Imaginary="<<imaginary<<endl;}
void set(int i,int j){real=i;imaginary=j;}
friend comp operator=(comp &op1,const comp &op2);
};

comp operator=(comp &op1,const comp &op2)
{
op1.imaginary=op2.imaginary;
op1.real=op2.real;
return op1;
}

int main()
{
comp a,b;
a.set(10,20);
b=a;
b.show();
return 0;
}
```

The compilation gives the following error :-

```
[root@dogmatix stackoverflow]# g++ prog4.cpp 
prog4.cpp:11: error: â€˜comp operator=(comp&, const comp&)â€™ must be a nonstatic member function
prog4.cpp:14: error: â€˜comp operator=(comp&, const comp&)â€™ must be a nonstatic member function
prog4.cpp: In function â€˜int main()â€™:
prog4.cpp:25: error: ambiguous overload for â€˜operator=â€™ in â€˜b = aâ€™
prog4.cpp:4: note: candidates are: comp& comp::operator=(const comp&)
prog4.cpp:14: note:                 comp operator=(comp&, const comp&)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The assignment operator is explicitly required to be a class member operator. That is a sufficient reason for the compiler to fail to compile your code. Assignment is one of the special member functions defined in the standard (like the copy constructor) that will be generated by the compiler if you do not provide your own.

Unlike other operations that can be understood as external to the left hand side operator, the assignment is an operation that is semantically bound to the left hand side: *modify this instance to be* equal *to the right hand side instance* (by some definition of *equal*), so it makes sense to have it as an operation of the class and not an external operation. On the other hand, other operators as addition are not bound to a particular instance: is `a+b` an operation of `a` or `b` or none of them? -- `a` and `b` are used in the operation, but the operation *acts* on the *result* value that is returned.

That approach is actually recommended and used: define `operator+=` (that applies to the instance) as a member function, and then implement `operator+` as a free function that operates on the *result*:

```
struct example {
   example& operator+=( const example& rhs );
};
example operator+( const example& lhs, const example& rhs ) {
   example ret( lhs );
   ret += rhs;
   return ret;
}
// usually implemented as:
// example operator+( example lhs, const example& rhs ) {
//    return lhs += rhs; // note that lhs is actually a copy, not the real lhs
//}
```

Comment: Your reasons aren't valid, because `operator=()` is not any more bound to the target instance than `operator+=()`, which *can* be defined outside class, because compiler will not interfere and introduce ambiguity.

Comment: I did not say that the semantics is what made the distinction, or else, as you state, all `operatorX=` would have to be member functions. The reason why it cannot be a free function is in the first paragraph: because the standard says so. I guess I was not clear --english is not my mother tongue -- I just meant to state that from the semantic point of view it makes more sense to have `operatorX=` (including `operator=`) as member functions even if `operatorX` is usually better implemented as a free function.

Comment: I guess the question was really why standard says so ;-)

Comment: There are some other quirks like that, why does `operator[]` have to be a member function? Why must `operator->` be member but `operator->*` can be implemented as a free function?

Answer (score 19):

Because if you do not declare it as a class member compiler will make one up for you and it will introduce ambiguity.

Comment: What is the signature for that overloaded "=" operator which compiler introduces automatically?

Comment: Same as yours but the return value is a reference.

Comment: I think it's a `TYPE& operator=(const TYPE&)`

Comment: ur, it couldn't be the same, because it only takes one parameter.

Comment: I think this answer is true, and I think it best explains what the compiler is doing and asking for (which is very important), but I don't think it explains why you shouldn't write the operator=() the way ashish-sangwan did in theory.

Comment: sheepsimulator, *in theory* you would be able to write it if not the reason stated above. Just think of the `operator+=()` that you can actually overload to do exactly what `operator=()` is supposed to do and implement it outside of the class. And I hate to talk about why people *SHOULD NOT* do things. They shouldn't do anything without understanding and if they understand there's nothing that should stop them from doing weird things.

Comment: The signature of the function the compiler generates depends on the members and bases of the class. If at least one of them have an assignment operator that takes a `Member&`, the compiler generated one for the class is `Class &Class::operator=(Class&)` and otherwise it's `Class &Class::operator=(Class const&)`

Answer (score 3):

Assignment(=) operator is a special operator that will be provided by the constructor to the class when programmer has not provided(overloaded) as member of the class.(like copy constructor).
When programmer is overloading = operator using friend function, two = operations will exists:
1) compiler is providing = operator
2) programmer is providing(overloading) = operator by friend function.
Then simply ambiguity will be created and compiler will gives error. Its compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

There is no good reason for that, I think Stepanov proposed that there should be a free `operator=` and many good stuff can be done with that (even more than what can be done with the move assignment). I can't find the citation but Stepanov went as a far as to suggest that the constructors could be free functions http://www.stlport.org/resources/StepanovUSA.html.

There is a way around it, which is to systematically *declare* a `template<class Other> A& operator=(Other const& t);` in inside all your classes, in this way you leave the option to anyone to define a custom assignment operator.

Of course you can't do this with a class you don't have control over.

Having said that it is nowadays not *that* bad since we have move assignment. And in some sense conversion operators `B::operator A() const{...}` are almost like a custom copy assignment. Conversion operators are now usable because of `explicit`. However you have to have control over the second type (`B`), the right-hand type in assignment.

Next question is why conversion operator need to be members them selves? Again, I don't think there is a good reason.