# Why can't the assignment operator be defined externally?

Tags: c++, reference, operator-overloading

I learned (through error) that, unlike other operators, `=` along with `()` and `[]` are required to be members of the class, and cannot be defined externally (for example, through `friend` functions).

I have gone through the following two posts:

(1) [Why can't we overload "=" using friend function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865036/)

(2) [C++ - On friend assignment-operator overloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60767817/)

Which address this issue, but I *still have a few questions*. I am specifically interested in the assignment `=` operator.

The [most upvoted answer in (1)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2865080/13709317) says:

> Because if you do not declare it as a class member compiler will make one up for you and it will introduce ambiguity.

Which I cannot quite understand.

I am taking the following code example:

```
class Demo {
    int x;
public:
    Demo(int x=0) {
        this->x = x;
    }
    friend void operator=(int&, const Demo&); // let's say hypothetically possible
};

void operator=(int& dest, const Demo& src)
{
    dest = src.x;
}

int main() {
    int x;
    Demo d(10);
    x = d; // call operator=(x, d)
}
```

If the "compiler makes one up for me", it would look something like below (according to the comments under the post):

```
TYPE& operator=(const TYPE&)
```

So, in my case:

```
Demo& operator=(const Demo&)
```

But, the one that *I* have defined externally looks like:

```
void operator=(int&, const Demo&)
```

So, where is the ambiguity that would result in this specific instance? Why can't I externally define `operator=` here specifically?

Post (2) was helpful in addressing my specific issue, and suggested using the `operator int()` conversion function instead:

> It follows that the only time when you can overload the assignment operator is when defining the class on the left-hand side. There is no way to write a custom assignment operator whose left-hand argument is a non-class type.
>
> In order to assign my_object to int, you need to write a (operator int) conversion function instead.

Comment: _A simple assignment operator function is a binary operator function named operator=. A simple assignment operator function shall be a non-static member function._ The standard specifies quite clearly that it must be a member function.

Comment: Your example has no use-case (I know it's an hypothetical, but things aren't added to C++ if their utility is nil). You want to control how your class converts to an integer? You can overload a conversion operator (which is applicable in way more places than just assignment).

Comment: I suspect post (1) was implicitly assuming one intends to overload as `T& operator=(T&, int);`

Comment: @ChrisMM I was wondering if there was a specific rationale for this. Like a counter example. But I'll be happy to accept it as "because the standard says so"---way simpler to be honest.

Comment: its like this because the standard says so. I don't think it is impossible to imagine a c++ where you could define an `operator=` that is not member of the class, but that wouldnt be c++. Consider that the class definition is complete at the `};` of the definition and by that time it is impossible to know if later a free function `=` is defined

Comment: is this not the same question as this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865036/why-cant-we-overload-using-friend-function/2865080#2865080 ?

Comment: fwiw, I dont think the most upvoted answer is the best. [The accepted  one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2865437/4117728) nails it when it starts with "The assignment operator is explicitly required to be a class member operator." full stop. Why it was specified like this is actually a different question

Comment: "Post (2) was helpful in addressing my specific issue and suggested using the operator int() conversion function instead:" Not sure if I understand this part. `operator=(int)` can be used for `int x = Demo{}`, but not for `Demo d; d = 42;`

Comment: You cannot override operators for embedded types, so you should show different example, your does not make any sense

Comment: @FirstUser An assignment operator from type `T` tells the compiler how to assign something to a `T`.  It is not used to tell the compiler how to assign a `T` to something else.  That is something elses job, to tell the compiler how to assign a `T` to it.

Comment: You can make your own externally defined "assignment function" by using a named function: `void assign(int&, Demo const&);`  No need to over think the problem, or overly rely on operator overloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do here:

```
int main() {
    int x;
    Demo d(10);
    x = d; // call operator=(x, d)
}
```

cannot be done by the `operator=` of `Demo`, because `Demo::operator=` assigns something to a `Demo` not the other way around. So whether `operator=` of `Demo` must be implemented as member or not is actually not that relevant for this particular code.

Also, generally you cannot overload operators for fundamental types like `int`. Hence, `operator=` member or not, as operator of `Demo` or operator of `int` is all not options for `x = d;`.

---

You can use `operator int`. Just don't miss to make it `explicit`, unless you are fully aware of implications of implicit conversions and are ready to face them:

```
class Demo {
    int x;
public:
    Demo(int x=0) : x(x) {}
    explicit operator int() { return x; }
};

int main() {
    int x;
    Demo d(10);
    x = static_cast<int>(d);
}
```

---

> Why can't I externally define operator= here specifically?

The reason is really that simple: Because the standard says so.

> So, where is the ambiguity that would result in this specific instance?

As stated above, the issue with `void operator=(int&, const Demo&)` is primarily that you cannot overload `operator=` that assigns to `int`.

I can only speculate what ambiguity the answer you quote refers to. The thing is that it is not impossible to imagine C++ where it is possible to define `operator=` as non-member without ambiguity. Its just not how C++ works. Consider this case:

```
 // class definition, no operator=
 struct foo { };  // I

 // free function:
 foo& operator=(foo& self,const foo& other) { 
      self.value = other.value; 
      return self;
 }
```

The class definition is complete after `(I)`. The compiler already did generate an `operator=` or should it not create one because there is a custom definition later?
The compiler could omit generation of `foo::operator=` when the class declares a free function with certain signature as friend. However, this would complicate the language for little to no gain. The advantage to free functions over member functions is that they must not be declared as part of the class definition.